# Не могу разобраться с меню для мобилок

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Вот линк на страницу: [http://uls.dtraduga.vh55.hosterby.com/discount_code1.php

Разрешение 1199 и меньше. 
На странице появляются дополнительный блок для выбора города и категории: [http://prntscr.com/lfqqum

На десктопе все нормально открывается и закрывается как положено. 
Но если мы переходим в DevTools и включаем мобильный решим для любого устройства: [http://prntscr.com/lfqrho]

То при нажатии на экран и удерживании мышки происходит вот такая беда: [http://prntscr.com/lfqrxd] :(((

И естественно все модалки тоже открываются непонятно как: [http://prntscr.com/lfqs9o]

Получается чтоли, что эти менюшки как бы все время отображаются справа и из-за них такая проблема: [http://prntscr.com/lfqsgk]

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: используйте .navigation_city { position: fixed;} вместо absolute

Answer (score 0):

Можно и через absolute было решить(необходимо только медиа выражения накинуть для разных экранов), но автор уже изменил верстку, не ясно что там было не так, как минимум я бы не стал делать это меню fixed на планшетной версии, получается что пока меню открыто, то остальной сайт недоступен, а это как по мне потеря юзабилити